# GPA Calculator. Problems with OR and dividing by 0

Tags: c++

I am writing a GPA calculator. I am having issues with the OR (||) function for checking if the input for credit is correct or no (If incorrect, it should ask again). Also, when the input for grades is "I" or "W" the program should not use that information (it should do nothing about it). 
Thank you before hand for the help.
Here is the code:

```
    // Include Statements
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Program to calculate GPA
int main()
{
    // Program made by Jose Luis Landivar
    // Fall 2016
    cout << ""<< endl;
    cout << "The following program will calculate your GPA "<< endl<<'\n';

    char grade;
    int g = 1;
    //variables for the algebraic operations needed
    int credit = 0;
    int totalcredit = 0;
    int ptotal = 0;
    double gpa, p = 1;
    double count = 1;
    double nclass;
    string coursename, coursenumber;


    cout << "Please enter the number of classes for the GPA calculator"<< endl;
        cin >> nclass;
    cout << ""<< endl;
    while (count <= nclass ) // While
    {
        //Information for the class
        cout << "Please enter the course name for the class # "<< count << endl;
            cin >> coursename;
        cout << "Please enter the course number for the class # "<< count << endl;
            cin >> coursenumber;

        //Getting grades and credits from user
        cout << "Enter the grade for the class # "<< count <<" (A,B,C,D,F,I,W)"<< endl;
            cin >> grade;
        if (grade == 'A' || grade == 'B' || grade == 'C' || grade == 'D' || grade == 'F' || grade == 'I' || grade == 'W')

        {

            // If for grades
            if (grade == 'A')
            {
                g = 4;
                cout << "Enter the number of credits for the class # "<< count <<" (1,2,3,4,5)"<< endl;
                    cin >> credit;
                cout << ""<< endl;
                if (credit == 5 || credit == 4 || credit == 3 || credit == 2 || credit == 1){
                    p = g * credit;
                    totalcredit = totalcredit + credit;
                    ptotal = ptotal + p;
                }
                else {cout << "Input is incorrect\n";
                }
            }


            if (grade == 'B')
            {
                g = 3;
                cout << "Enter the number of credits for the class # "<< count <<" (1,2,3,4,5)"<< endl;
                    cin >> credit;
                cout << ""<< endl;
                if (credit == 5 || credit == 4 || credit == 3 || credit == 2 || credit == 1){
                    p = g * credit;
                    totalcredit = totalcredit + credit;
                    ptotal = ptotal + p;
                }
                else {cout << "Input is incorrect\n";
                }
            }

            if (grade == 'C')
            {
                g = 2;
                cout << "Enter the number of credits for the class # "<< count <<" (1,2,3,4,5)"<< endl;
                    cin >> credit;
                cout << ""<< endl;
                if (credit == 5 || credit == 4 || credit == 3 || credit == 2 || credit == 1){
                    p = g * credit;
                    totalcredit = totalcredit + credit;
                    ptotal = ptotal + p;
                }
                else {cout << "Input is incorrect\n";
                }
            }

            if (grade == 'D')
            {
                g = 1;
                cout << "Enter the number of credits for the class # "<< count <<" (1,2,3,4,5)"<< endl;
                    cin >> credit;
                cout << ""<< endl;
                if (credit == 5 || credit == 4 || credit == 3 || credit == 2 || credit == 1){
                    p = g * credit;
                    totalcredit = totalcredit + credit;
                    ptotal = ptotal + p;
                }
                else {cout << "Input is incorrect\n";
                }
            }

            if (grade == 'F')
            {
                g = 0;
                cout << "Enter the number of credits for the class # "<< count <<" (1,2,3,4,5)"<< endl;
                    cin >> credit;
                cout << ""<< endl;
                if (credit == 5 || credit == 4 || credit == 3 || credit == 2 || credit == 1){
                    p = g * credit;
                    totalcredit = totalcredit + credit;
                    ptotal = ptotal + p;
                }
                else {cout << "Input is incorrect\n";
                }
            }

            count = count + 1;
        }

        else {cout << "Input is incorrect\n";
        }
    }
    //algebraic formulas
    gpa = ptotal/totalcredit;

    //output results
    cout << "Your total number of credits is: " << totalcredit << endl;
    cout << "Your GPA is: " << gpa << endl;

    if (grade == 'I')
    {
    }
    if (grade == 'W')
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I am having issues with the OR (||) function" can you state what issues do you have with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful when comparing `int` to `char`. For example:

```
int credit = 3;

// THIS WILL FAIL
if (credit == '3') {
}
```

an int of 3 and a char of '3' will NOT be equal. Although you can compare a char and an int they dont have the same value. For instance

```
cout << "Int : " << int(3) << std::endl;
cout << "Char: " << int('3') << std::endl;
```

gives the output:

```
Int : 3
Char: 51
```

You should change every occurance of

```
if (credit == '5' || credit == '4' || credit == '3' || credit == '2' || grade == '1'){
                                                                     // ^^^ is this suppose to be "credit"?
```

to

```
if (credit == 5 || credit == 4 || credit == 3 || credit == 2 || credit == 1){
```

**UPDATE**
Note that your code is never actually doing anything when "I" or "W" is provided (other than incrementing the course `count` variable as it should). However, when *EVERY* course is either "I" or "W" (i.e. all courses are (I)ncomplete or (W)ithdrawl) then your `totalcredit` variable will be equal to 0 giving you the 'divide by 0' error. Change

```
//algebraic formulas
gpa = ptotal/totalcredit;
```

to

```
if (totalcredit > 0) {
   gpa = ptotal/totalcredit;
} else {
   gpa = 0;
}
```

The else statement probably isnt necessary (`gpa` will already be zero), but it makes it explicit exactly what you want the GPA to be when there are no valid credits to compute the GPA from.

Comment: Issue with the OR function was solved. Still do not know what to do when user input is "I" or "W"

Comment: From your question above, it sounds like when the user gives "I" or "W" you basically want to ignore it, which i believe is what you're already doing in your code. I'm not sure how GPAs are calculated for (I)ncompletes or (W)ithdrawl. Some schools calculate incompletes as "F" in the GPA until the course is completed. Most schools probably dont include withdrawls in the GPA.

Comment: For this assignment  courses with W or I grades do not have to be used in the GPA calculation. But in these case when input one of those values the program use it as a part of the GPA calculation and gives me the dividing by 0 error.

Comment: See my update on how to handle the case when totalcredits is 0